# Why is it considered bad to regenerate package lock file?

Tags: yarnpkg, package.json

So I have a problem that package install gets stuck when running `yarn install` for my project. Removing `yarn.lock` and then running `yarn install` seems to resolve the issue. However, some people say that you should never delete the lock file because it might break the dependencies. Can someone explain how exactly does that work? And if I shouldn't regenerate or manually modify the lock file, what is the correct way to approach this kind of issues?

Comment: Something might break because `package.json` only contains your direct dependencies, and usually with specs that allow a range of versions (`^` and `~`, see e.g. https://semver.npmjs.com/). `yarn.lock` contains all direct _and transitive_ dependencies, with _specific versions_ for everything. If you delete the lockfile and reinstall, you could end up with a different dependency tree - still compatible with the package requirements, but potentially including issues you didn't have before if any of those changes introduce bugs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe does it make a difference if I pin all my direct dependencies, i.e. use only specific versions in `package.json`?

Comment: Probably not - almost certainly some of your direct or transitive dependencies _won't_ pin specific versions of _their_ dependencies.